# Does `sudo` work in terms of changing the effective user and group IDs of a process?

Tags: sudo, uid

Does `sudo` give the `root`'s power to a command by changing the effective user and group IDs of the process of the command to be `root`?

If not, how does `sudo` work to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, generally that's what it does. Though `sudo` is very powerful and can be configured to do other things too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html):

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the **security policy**.
>
> [...]
>
> When sudo executes a command, the security policy specifies the execution environment for the command. **Typically, the real and effective user and group and IDs are set to match those of the target user**, as specified in the password database, and the group vector is initialized based on the group database (unless the -P option was specified).
>
> The following parameters **may be** specified by security policy:
>
> - real and effective user ID
> - real and effective group ID
> - supplementary group IDs
> - the environment list
> - current working directory
> - file creation mode mask (umask)
> - SELinux role and type
> - Solaris project
> - Solaris privileges
> - BSD login class
> - scheduling priority (aka nice value)

To answer your question, changing the effective user and group ID's of a process is only one way of changing the privileges of a process, the security policy defined in [`sudo.conf`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.conf.man.html) can use any other kind of parameters in the above list.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Are both real and effective user/group IDs changed to those of the target user? or just the effective user/group IDs?   (2) "changing the effective user and group ID's of a process is only one way of changing the privileges of a process". What are other ways of changing the privileges of a process? See See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440316/why-does-sudo-change-both-effective-and-real-user-group-ids-instead-of-just-e?noredirect=1&lq=1