# How does sudo achieve changing the privileges of a process?

Tags: sudo, uid

1. From `man sudo`

   > When sudo executes a command, the security policy specifies the
   >   execution environment for the command. Typically, **the real and
   >   effective user and group and IDs are set to match those of the target
   >   user**, as specified in the password database, and the group vector is
   >   initialized based on the group database (unless the -P option was
   >   specified).

   Why does `sudo` change **both** effective and real user/group IDs to
   those of the target user, instead of **just** effective user/group IDs?

   Are effective user/group IDs not the only ones needed to take on the
   privileges of the target user?
2. From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333245/674

   > changing the effective user and group ID's of a process is only one way of changing the privileges of a process, the security policy
   >   defined in sudo.conf can use any other kind of parameters in the
   >   above list.

   In order to change the privileges, are there other ways than
   changing the effective user/group IDs? What are they?

Thanks.

My question is inspired from [Does `sudo` work in terms of changing the effective user and group IDs of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333236/does-sudo-work-in-terms-of-changing-the-effective-user-and-group-ids-of-a-proc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `sudo` changes both the real and effective user ids in order to *restrict* the resulting process’ privileges. Changing the effective id is *sufficient* to grant the new process the privileges of the requested user, but doing only that leaves open a gaping hole: [`setuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html) can then be used to assume the privileges of the calling user. To avoid that, `sudo` sets the real user id too.
2. The list of possibilities is given in [the `sudo` manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html) and quoted in the answer you’re referring to. Some of those have an impact on the child process’ privileges: the SELinux role and type, the Solaris project and privileges, and the BSD login class.